# Inconsistent session variable

Tags: session, iis, asp-classic

We have a session variable that we use to save the user country. The value of this variable sometimes changes and we are sure there is no place in our code that change this value, for example sometimes it shows USA and some times it shows France within the same session! We experience this problem on different machines and different networks.

We tried to print the session id and we noticed that the session ID is changed at the same time the country session change! What does that mean?

Our server is dedicated and hosted by Godaddy, we only use one worker process, there is no web gardens or web farms.

Any suggestions?

Comment: for help with trouble shooting use Response.Write(Session.SessionID) to see if the session ID is changing with the changes in country.

Comment: Yes sessionID is changing with the changes in country! What does that mean?

Comment: Then for some reason your session isn't being stored. As far as I know with ASP it should autmaticaly do session start but try adding <%@ ENABLESESSIONSSTATE=True %> to the top of your page and see if the session stays.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means you have a problem in your code - which we can't see, or the session has expired and a new one has been created for the user.

Different session id's with different session countries can be expected.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with our code, to support this claim I have a created an empty test page that set a new session variable with user ip address(set this variable when it's empty) and we noticed the same behavior!

Comment: What is the session expiration time?  Once it expires a new one is generated for the user next request.

Comment: 20 minutes. Even if it's expired it should not change the user IP or country.